# In a restaurant, 16 men & 10 women are seated on 26 chairs at a round table. How many possible ways men are always seated together?

Tags: combinatorics

In a restaurant, 16 men and 10 women are seated on 26 chairs at a round table. Find the total number of possible ways such that 16 men are always sitting next to each other.

I've arrived at the solution of $16!.10!$ But I suppose the answer cannot be as simple as this, is my approach and answer correct?

It is challenging for me to frame the solution correctly.

Comment: Under the usual convention that two permutations are considered to be equivalent if one can be obtained from the other by rotation, your answer is correct.  Why do you have doubts?

Comment: No, the seats are not distinguishable or numbered. Only condition is all men shall be seated next to each other.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I'm super doubtful because I submitted the last assignment with confidence and scored in single digit, I don't want to fail.

Comment: A good way to deal with circular tables is to specify one of the people as "special" ahead of time, say it was Mrs. $X$, and to say "*[Without loss of generality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) suppose that Mrs. $X$ was seated at the northernmost seat of the table.*"  You then arrange all of the remaining people around the table *with respect to* Mrs. $X$'s initial position.

Comment: By doing so, you do arrive at an answer of $16!$ ways to arrange the men within their block, and $10!$ ways to arrange the $10$ people/blocks around the table in the remaining seats which consist of the nine women other than Mrs. $X$ and the block of men treated as a single entity for this step for a total of $16!\cdot 10!$ arrangements.

Comment: Alternatively, think of arranging two objects around the table, a block of men and a block of women.  The block of women must be adjacent to the block of men.  The men can be arranged within their block in $16!$ ways.  The women can be arranged within their block in $10!$ ways.  Hence, there are $16!10!$ admissible arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

On a circular table, $n$ objects can be arranged in $(n-1)!$ ways.

*First arrange all the women on the circular table.*

> $10$ women can be arranged in $(10-1)! = 9!$ ways on a circular table.

*Now we need to arrange $16$ men such that all of them are together.*

We can arrange these men in any of the $10$ gaps between the women. (Assume that we have tied up all the men together and are considering them as a single element).

> For arranging this element (all the men) in $10$ gaps, there are $10$ ways.

But these men can also change their order. So, multiply $10$ with the factorial of number of men i.e. $16!$.

So the required number of ways are,
$$9! \cdot 10 \cdot 16! = 10! \cdot 16!$$

**Hence your answer is correct!**

Answer (score 0):

There will be just one woman who has at her right a man. Where this happens is irrelevant, as we distinguish guest placements only by looking at neighbors. Now open up the circle at that point to have first a line of $10$ women and then a line of $16$ men.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your confusion is arising  from the fact that you have been told again and again that if $N$ objects are arranged in an *unnumbered* circle, the number of arrangements is $(n-1)!$, or equivalently, $\dfrac{n!}{n}$, against $n!$ arrangements in a *numbered* circle.

True, here we have an *unnumbered* circle, but the crucial difference is that we have two adjacent **blocks** of men and women, $\boxed{M}\boxed{W}$

Applying the formula for circular arrangements, the blocks can be permuted in $(2-1)! \equiv \dfrac{2!}{2}$ ways, but the men and women can be permuted *within* the blocks in $M!N!$ ways